# Add new privilege: reduce minimum character requirement for comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, privileges

Can we add a new privilege to allow for very short comments?

Just an idea, but I often just write `[mcve]`. Our time is precious and I have nothing more to say; I end up writing useless words to fill the minimum characters required.

Let's say at `8000` points (totally random) users are allow to write comments with 3 characters? (`[a]` for minimum magic link?)

---

I feel like people are just seeing my use case but more generally, what is the point to force comments to be at least 15 chars? Limit bot spam, prevent comments like "Thanks", etc, but my point is at 8000 points can we trust users to write good comments even if they are very short ones?

Comment: If that is all you are going to say then why would you even post such comment. It's absolutely useless. Just close the question and move on.

Comment: I agree that only providing an mcve link with no context is fairly useless. Keep a copy/paste list of comments you repeat handy instead or use a userscript that auto fills comments

Comment: @charlietfl I don't like be a copy paste machine sorry

Comment: Except when its "mcve"? Not sure I see the difference! - https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Comment: The 6 characters needed for a `[mcve]` or `[help]` quick link are already 40% of the 15 character minimum. Sounds like over optimization of your time to me

Comment: @charlietfl totally, currently I write "[mcve] blablabla" notice that the link expend to more than 15 characters anyway...

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't like must this I tried but it's too annoying to use, also comment should be short. All information are already explained in [mcve], I will just repeat information in the link.

Comment: @Stargateur You are dealing with people, not machines. Such a comment is not optimal if the intention is to encourage the OP to rework their question.

Comment: would be interesting to twist this request a bit: _increase_ comments char limit for new users, so that current limit would become a rep-gained privilege, just as requested here

Comment: Using keyboard shortcuts this is **m** -> **c** -> **2** -> **4** -> Enter - five keystrokes total. Stands for **M**oderate -> **C**lose -> "A community-specific reason" (**2**nd from the top) -> "Needs debugging details" (**4**th from the top) -> Vote to close.

Comment: 1. Have an optimization idea saving .5 seconds per comment. 2. Spend an amount of time on Meta roughly equivalent to 2 comments per day for the next couple of months. 3. ... 4. Profit! In all seriousness, I'd rather see the minimum (and, frankly, maximum) comment length increased rather than decreased.

Comment: There is too much manual typing in this world. Just use canned comments with complete sentences (copy-pasted from somewhere (or typed out by a macro keyboard)).

Comment: Good idea, but bad example. If someone asks a yes/no question, then I'd prefer to be able to give a yes/no answer, not need to think about how to pad it out.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this feature adds anything of value. In general, your comments should be tailored to the specific situation, and it should be clear what you're trying to communicate. While one can be clear with a comment that says just "yes", or "no", for example, I don't think there's anything lost by not being able to communicate that. In fact, allowing fewer than 15 character comments will likely have the negative effect of resulting in a larger number of comments that aren't useful. Basically, if what you have to say doesn't need more than 15 characters, then what you have to say probably isn't worth saying.

Your example of writing a comment containing just "[mcve]" is a good example of a redundant comment, because there is a close reason that communicates this very well. Simply vote/flag to close the question as "Needing debugging details", and don't bother leaving a comment at all. If you think the question shouldn't be closed because the OP just needs to add a couple of details, you need to be specific in your comment anyway, and that will definitely be over the character limit.

Comment: closing a question is feel with a lot of negativity so we often give a 24h delay to improve a question, I'm not the best to be neutral and often my comment get deleted by moderation so I try to keep it short. comment with a link where the content is hosted by SO make my comment safe. The only thing I could write is "please do a [mcve]" but as I said I'm lazy. I expect that a link is enough to say "click on the link". (and in practice it's work, I often just write "[mcve] jdlkazjdkaznkezjn" and the question get edited properly)

Comment: @Stargateur Yes, closing a question can make the OP feel bad, but we need to close questions that are not up to the standards expected on the site. I strongly suggest not waiting for 24 hours for the OP to improve the question. After all, they had plenty of time before posting to write a good question. Instead, vote to close it straight away, and then vote to reopen if the question does get improved. Also, I understanding not wanting to type out a comment if you're repeating it often, but in that case, you can just paste a canned comment.

Comment: that is very bad, as we first hope that with a comment the user improves his question, before downvoting and closing.

Comment: @nbk I'm not entirely sure what you mean. You can of course help the OP improve the question to be on-topic if you want. However, that is not what most users should be doing; off-topic questions should be closed as soon as possible, and it's simply not reasonable for all the close voters to be spending time leaving comments in the hope that the OP will improve the question. Basically, comments should not be used as a substitute for close votes. In the cases where the OP *does* improve the question, you can cast a reopen vote.

Comment: [How soon should I “vote to close”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98022)

Comment: @cigien we add [mre] to a question when the question has not enough infomation, and we add a canonical or to to the mix, sothat the user can improve their question.so that is a shortcut,that comes very very often in comments, because the new user but also the old can't often understand what we need to give an answer. this is better tahne the reviews that almost veryone hates, because the are to big to get the  question reopen. so fiirst comment and then close